# Change a div element inside $(this)

Tags: jquery

I am trying to change a certain div element inside a click event.
My question is how do I choose this element?
For example,

```
$("#a").live('click', function(){
$('.b').html('text') // I want to change class 'b' inside  $(this).parent() and not all 'b' classes
});
```

Comment: There you go: http://api.jquery.com/find/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may do the trick:

```
$(this).find('.b').html('text');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with more than one way!

## one way

```
$('#el').on('click', function(){
 $(this).parent().find('.something').text('new text'); 
});
```

## here's another way

```
$('#el').on('click', function(){
 $(this).next('.something').text('new text'); //or closest
});
```

Hope this can help!